# How does cin works in a while loop when the inputs are given in a single line with white spaces?

Tags: c++, cin

Consider this small piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int a;  

while(true){
cin>>a;
cout<<a;
}
return 0;
}
```

**Input**
1 2 3 5 7 23

**Output**
125723

How I thought it will run is:
**First iteration**
1. Reads the first input ie '1' and stops reading further, right after reading the whitespace.
2.Prints the value 1.
**Second iteration**
1. Again asks for new input
2. Print that in the second line
But that doesn't happen instead it reads the elements we gave after space

Comment: Why do you think it would print in a second line?

Comment: "*Print that in the second line*" - nope, because you are not telling it to. If every call to `<<` output a new line then you couldn't chain multiple `<<` calls together to format individual lines with multiple values. If you want line breaks, you have to print them explicitly, eg: `cout << a << '\n';` or `cout << a << endl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First iteration:

- Peek at next character in the stream. It's a digit (`'1'`), so read it.
- Peek at next character in the stream. It's not a digit (`' '`), so don't read it; store `1` in `a` and return from `>>`.

(Output `1`.)

Second iteration:

- Peek at next character in the stream. It's whitespace (`' '`), so read and ignore it.
- Peek at next character in the stream. It's a digit (`'2'`), so read it.
- Peek at next character in the stream. It's not a digit (`' '`), so don't read it; store `2` in `a` and return from `>>`.

(Output `2`.)

And so on ...

The point is that `>>` does not care about lines. `cin` is one long input stream of characters (some of which may be `'\n'`). The only thing you can do is read more characters (and then maybe decide that you don't want to do anything with them).

`cin` is not necessarily connected to a keyboard. The program that started you gets to decide where `cin` reads from. It can be a file, a network socket, or interactive user input. In the latter case, reading from `cin` may block until the user types more input, but it will never cause input to just be dropped.

If you want a sane user interface, always read whole lines and process them afterwards:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    // do stuff with line
}
```

Comment: This is nice explanation of how input works here, but I think it doesn't address main OP's misconception, which is really about `cout << a` not producing new lines.

Comment: @Frax I interpret "*1. Again asks for new input. 2. Print that in the second line*" as "I expect it to wait for another line of input, then print the first number in that second line (of input)."

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you are right. The question is pretty ambiguous, actually.